# usb device -> block device mapping on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, device

Apologies if this is a duplicate, however.

I have 2 usb mass storage devices, and I need to be able to work out which physical device maps to a block device.

They are not both always present, so I can't just rely on a fixed block device path.

I've tried to determine the device path from `lsusb`, but that just provides the device info.

```
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 0781:5406 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Micro 1/2/4GB Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 4971:ce23 SimpleTech
```

`sudo fdisk -l` is not able to read any partition as its a truecrypt encrypted volume.

Is there some way to detect which physical device is mapped to a block device ?

I'm not able to mount the filesystem until I know which is which.

have I approached this problem in the wrong way ?

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the physical devices both the same size? Are they the exact same brand as well?

If they are different sizes, `fdisk -l` should show you the size of the entire disk in the header along with the block device name, which should help you.

You can also check the output of `dmesg`. When a USB device is connected, `dmesg` will display the process it undergoes to bring it online, as well as showing you the block device it assigned. Here's a sample output:

```
Aug 14 16:35:02 xen kernel: [2526561.710931] usb 5-5: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
Aug 14 16:35:02 xen kernel: [2526561.859909] usb 5-5: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Aug 14 16:35:02 xen kernel: [2526562.138808] usbcore: registered new interface driver libusual
Aug 14 16:35:02 xen kernel: [2526562.162072] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
Aug 14 16:35:02 xen kernel: [2526562.163248] scsi4 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
Aug 14 16:35:02 xen kernel: [2526562.163452] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
Aug 14 16:35:02 xen kernel: [2526562.163455] USB Mass Storage support registered.
Aug 14 16:35:07 xen kernel: [2526567.161157] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WDC WD50 00AAKS-00A7B0         PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS
Aug 14 16:35:07 xen kernel: [2526567.171712] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 976773168 512-byte hardware sectors (500108 MB)
Aug 14 16:35:07 xen kernel: [2526567.172736] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Aug 14 16:35:07 xen kernel: [2526567.173733] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 976773168 512-byte hardware sectors (500108 MB)
Aug 14 16:35:07 xen kernel: [2526567.174606] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Aug 14 16:35:13 xen kernel: [2526567.174616]  sdb: sdb1
Aug 14 16:35:13 xen kernel: [2526572.854493] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
Aug 14 16:35:13 xen kernel: [2526572.854544] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
```

As you can see, the kernel assigned /dev/sdb to the USB device. Hope this helps!

Comment: I think i'll write a small wrapper script around dmesg to provide the most recent mapping for the USB devices.

Thankyou for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can query sysfs to report the vendor and model of the drive:

```
$ cat /sys/block/sdd/device/{vendor,model}
DSE     
MicroDrive 1GB  

$ cat /sys/block/sdc/device/{vendor,model}
JetFlash
Transcend 4GB
```

If you want to go further than that, you could add udev rules (assuming your linux distro has udev) to map your different drives to different device names, or to provide a different symlink based on the drive model

EG, [here](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#example-usbhdd) has some examples.

I could do something like this to create a /dev/transcend symlink, with partition numbers appended where appropriate, to whatever real device is actually created when I insert my Transcend stick:

```
KERNEL=="sd*", SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi", ATTRS{model}==\ 
 "Transcend 4GB", SYMLINK+="transcend%n"
```

Of course, if I put in multiple devices of the same model, there would be a collision, but with a bit of work you can get around that

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering what to do in the case where there are multiple devices with the same vendor:product IDs.

I tried running `udevadm info -a /dev/sde`, which "walks up the chain of parent devices" (whatever that means?). By matching "ATTRS{devnum}" and "ATTRS{busnum}" with the Bus X Device Y output of `lsusb`, I could see that not only did the udevadm listing produce the bus and device numbers for the USB hard drive as a "parent" of the block device `/dev/sde`, but also the bus and device numbers of the hub it was connected to as well as the host controller! That could be useful if you want to identify a device by the port it's connected to.

I was a bit confused about why it seems so hard to get the USB device corresponding to a given block device, and I guess this clears that up a bit: the devices are not the same, there is a kind of filial relationship between the two.

Udevadm gives the paths of each parent, so you have some idea how to locate the correct parent by trimming the child path:

```
$ udevadm info --path=$(udevadm info -q path /dev/sde | cut -d / -f 1-7)
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-2/2-2.4
N: bus/usb/002/024
E: BUSNUM=002
E: DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/002/024
E: DEVNUM=024
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-2/2-2.4
E: DEVTYPE=usb_device
E: DRIVER=usb
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_MODEL=External_HDD
....
```

We can pass the DEVNAME to lsusb:

```
$ lsusb -D $(udevadm info --path=$(udevadm info -q path /dev/sde
    | cut -d / -f 1-7) | grep DEVNAME | cut -d = -f 2)
Device: ID 1058:0705 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. My Passport Elite (WDML)
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
...
```

So we can use this to tell that, for example, /dev/sde is connected as a USB 2.0 device (from the bcdUSB line above).

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but it gives a way to identify USB devices from block devices. Also it is not quite complete because I think you'll have to give a different argument to 'cut' if you don't have a hub in-between the controller and the device. Probably I should be counting from the end of the device path, rather than the beginning, but I couldn't find a way to pass a numeric argument to `dirname`.

Update: Here is a solution that uses zsh to trim components from the end of the device path, let me know if it works for you:

```
$ cat usb-device-from-block-device
#!/bin/zsh                         
udevadm info --path ${${$(udevadm info -q path $1)}%/*/*/*/*/*/*} | grep DEVNAME | cut -d = -f 2

# Example:
$ usb-device-from-block-device /dev/sdc
/dev/bus/usb/001/017
$ lsusb -D $(usb-device-from-block-device /dev/sdc)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you connect a device you can visit /dev/disk and go from there knowing that the symlinks there get created dynamically:

```
[user@host disk]$ pwd
/dev/disk
[user@host disk]$ ll -R
.:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  80 Jul 30 09:54 by-id
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  80 Jul 30 09:54 by-label
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 160 Jul 30 09:54 by-path
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  80 Jul 30 09:54 by-uuid

./by-id:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jul 30 09:54 usb-WD_10EAVS_External_57442D574341553436313337373137 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul 30 09:54 usb-WD_10EAVS_External_57442D574341553436313337373137-part1 -> ../../sdb1

./by-label:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul 30 09:54 backup -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar  3 18:51 boot -> ../../sda1

./by-path:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jul 30 09:54 pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:6:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul 30 09:54 pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:6:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Mar  3 18:51 pci-0000:00:1f.1-ide-0:0 -> ../../hda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Mar  3 18:51 pci-0000:02:0e.0-scsi-0:2:0:0 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar  3 18:51 pci-0000:02:0e.0-scsi-0:2:0:0-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar  3 18:51 pci-0000:02:0e.0-scsi-0:2:0:0-part2 -> ../../sda2

./by-uuid:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar  3 18:51 72734cea-d59d-443b-8fdd-3e7a0e2c7731 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul 30 09:54 efcb8d1e-3f46-4021-bc55-22a85846429b -> ../../sdb1
[user@host disk]$
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen a UUID-centric answer, so here's one:

If you have a filesystem on that device, that filesystem has a UUID. You can use this UUID to mount the filesystem reliably, no matter what device major/minor block device the flash drive comes in as on the system

You can easily display which device goes to which UUID/filesystem with `lsblk -f`. The following is an example from my system, which shows a nice descriptive tree off of my single NVMe drive. The flash drives in this question would probably present a much simpler output.

```
[dhay@GLaDOS ~]$ lsblk -f
NAME              FSTYPE      LABEL       UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1                                                                          
├─nvme0n1p1       vfat        ESP         F2F6-9BC7                              /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2                                                                      
├─nvme0n1p3       crypto_LUKS             abde2123-0ee9-46b5-8d05-2b0b91b21054   
│ └─syspvluks     LVM2_member             ZsBxHH-tvRz-xE3k-e2dJ-I0O0-Gv4e-Ckap71 
│   ├─system-root xfs         root        a3acf72b-3309-408e-b6a4-0c3f28b86a53   /
│   └─system-swap swap        swap        5006f803-af24-4179-a5fa-7c5720b383d2   [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p4       ntfs        WINRETOOLS  A0B0BED5B0BEB0E0                       
├─nvme0n1p5       ntfs        Image       D6E6BF67E6BF4711                       
├─nvme0n1p6       ntfs        DELLSUPPORT 00CED73ECED72AA4                       
└─nvme0n1p7       xfs         boot        b3e3a722-e37a-4c15-8d6c-4085c00b778a   /boot
```

With that UUID in hand, you can identify filesystems with it regardless of what they're on. This is also great for migrating a filesystem from one device to another without having to update any configuration. The following is an exmaple of my /etc/fstab file, which is using a combination of device labels, UUIDs, and LVM persistent names rather than direct kernel names for block devices:

```
/dev/mapper/system-root /                       xfs     defaults,discard       0 0
UUID=F2F6-9BC7          /boot/efi               vfat    umask=0077,shortname=winnt 0 2
/dev/mapper/system-swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
LABEL=boot              /boot                   xfs     defaults,discard     0 0
```

Likewise, I can use a UUID as a device argument in this `mount` command to mount my root filesystem to a directory :

`[dhay@GLaDOS ~]$ mount UUID=a3acf72b-3309-408e-b6a4-0c3f28b86a53 /mnt/root`